# Split Only Values from Json Response

Tags: jquery, json

Json

```
 var Data = [{"selectedtedQ":0},{"selectedtedQ":2},{"selectedtedQ":1},{"selectedtedQ":0},{"selectedtedQ":0}]
```

Expected

```
 var Data = [0,2,1,0,0]
```

Try Jquery

```
 $.ajax({
          type: "Post",
            url: "FeedBackGraph.aspx/getServicewisedata",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
               success: function (Response)
               {
                 var d = Response.d.toString(); // [{"selectedtedQ":0},{"selectedtedQ":2},{"selectedtedQ":1},{"selectedtedQ":0},{"selectedtedQ":0}]
                  var res = d.map(Number);
                  console.log(res);
               }
             error: function (result) {
            }
            });
```

`d.map(Number);` return a `NAN` Value, How to get all the values out of a json object ?

Comment: `d.map(Number)`...`Number` is undefined in your code as far as I can see, so it's not clear why you'd expect this to do anything useful? Also, if you want to do something with an Object, why covert it to a string first (i.e. your Response.d.toString() code)? It's must easier to deal with when it's an object. jQuery already converted the JSON (string) into an object for you, don't change it back to a string again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map(Number)` will convert objects in array to Number which will be **NaN**.

As you want to get the value from an object. Try following

```js
 var d = [{"selectedtedQ":0},{"selectedtedQ":2},{"selectedtedQ":1},{"selectedtedQ":0},{"selectedtedQ":0}];
let res = d.map(o => o.selectedtedQ);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @aparnarai - Have you correctly picked the code like earlier in my code name of variable was `Data` as compared to `d` in your code. Can you please check?

Comment: @aparnarai this code is working - you can see it if you press "Run code snippet"...if it doesn't work for you, double-check your version. Probably in your version the first line would need to be `var d = Response.d;` (without the toString() of course!!) to get the data from the Response.